# take several values from textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Im using MVC 3.0 .NET 4.0, Razor and Kendo UI framework.

I have tree textboxes and I need take the values from each one and passing to MVC controller.

I cannot receive the values from textboxes.

IE:

file.cshtml

```
<input type="text" id="tb0" />
<input type="text" id="tb1" />
<input type="text" id="tb2" />

<button type="submit" id="btnSave">Send</button>
```

jsfile.js

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  var variable1 = new Array(); //I dont know how to send this values to the controller
  variable1[0] = $('#tb0').val();
  variable1[1] = $('#tb1').val();
  variable1[2] = $('#tb2').val();

  var model = {

     representative1: variable1

  }

  $.ajax({

     url: rootFolder + 'Controller1/Method1',
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(model), 
     dataType: 'json',
     processData: false,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: OnSuccessSave,
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(genericError);

    }
  });
}
```

Class1.cs

```
public class Class1
{
        public Class1()
        {
           this.representative1 = new Representative();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public Representative representative1 {get; set;}
 }
```

Representant.cs

```
public class Representative
{
       public string tb0 { get; set; }
       public string tb1 { get; set; }
       public string tb2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller1.cs

```
public class Controller1
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Method1 (Class1 model) 
    {
        //The "model" var dont receive the textboxes values.

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

Comment: Less code my friend... we are not gonna read all of it :)

Comment: Sorry, that is necessary, if not, you will not understand the flow and the problem

Comment: not difficult to follow, come on :)

Comment: Can you do an alert of the `variable1`  values to see you are getting them well?

Comment: Yes, they are getting well. I can see them on chrome debug console

Comment: Are you forgetting to close the `click` event? Or is it a typo. You need the ');' after the last '}'.

Comment: No, i forgot to copy here. It works ok

Comment: When I said "dont receive the textboxes values", I mean I can see the vars but emptys (null) all of them.